# How to replace the offcanvas image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sass

I´m building a menu where I want to have a full logo when in large screen and a short logo (with only the product brand image) if the image is offcanvas.

My current SCSS:

```
#header {
  background-color: $header-bg;
  z-index: 1001;
  @include transition(right .25s $ease-in-circ, padding-right .25s $ease-in-circ);

  .branding {
    background-color: $sidebar-bg;
    width: 250px;
    height: 45px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 15px;

    img.brand {
      color: white;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-top: 10px;
      height: 40px;
      float: left;
      @include transition(none);

      &:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
    }

    .offcanvas-toggle {
      color: white;
      margin-left: 5px;
      opacity: .5;
      padding: 1px 4px;
      font-size: 18px;

      &:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

And HTML elements:

```
<header class="clearfix">

  <!-- Branding -->
  <div class="branding {{main.settings.brandingColor}}">
        <img src="/app/images/logo.png" class="brand" ui-sref="app.dashboard" alt="MyApp">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="offcanvas-toggle visible-xs-inline" offcanvas-sidebar><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Branding end -->
</header>
```

The way it is now, if I shrink the window the original logo stays there. Where should I put the alternative logo ? In another `<img>` tag ?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a small thing you haven't noticed in your code. In SCSS, you have mentioned `#header`. But in html, there is no `id` attribute. Anyway, in my snippet below I have removed the background color variables and transitions to simplifying the code. The snippet supports only css I guess. So I needed to add the pre-processed css.

```css
#header .branding {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
#header .branding .brand {
  width: 250px;
  height: 45px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
}
#header .branding .brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #header .branding .brand {
    display: none;
  }
}
#header .branding .sml-brand-img {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  #header .branding .sml-brand-img {
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 45px;
  }
}
#header .branding .offcanvas-toggle {
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
  opacity: .5;
  padding: 1px 4px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#header .branding .offcanvas-toggle:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="clearfix">
  <!-- Branding -->
  <div class="branding">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/45/" class="brand" ui-sref="app.dashboard" alt="MyApp">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/45" class="sml-brand-img" alt="MyApp">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="offcanvas-toggle visible-xs-inline" offcanvas-sidebar><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Branding end -->
</header>
```